# can't replace duplicate values with new values in xlsx with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an `xlsx` file containing too much data. however the data contains `duplicate` values in column named `UniversalIDS` which I wanted to replace it with a randomly generated `IDS` with `Pandas`.

So far I've tried different scenarios which I googled but did not work. for example I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import uuid

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Nervous/Downloads/ss.xlsx')

df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=["UniversalIDS"]), "UniversalIDS"] = uuid.uuid4()


df.to_excel("C:/Users/Nervous/Downloads/tt.xlsx")

print("done!")
```

also I tried other alternatives seen on this site like for example:

```
 df2 = df.assign(UniversalIDS=df['UniversalIDS'].where(
    ~df.duplicated(['UniversalIDS']), uuid.uuid4()))
```

also this didn't work:

```
df.loc[df["UniversalIDS"].duplicated(), "test"]
```

this is a snippet from `xlsx data`:

```
UniversalIDS
f6112cd7-0868-4cc9-b5ab-d7381cc23bdf
f3e75641-f328-429f-ae32-41399d8a0bf0
08dccc5c-5774-4614-925c-ad9373821075
79a8ebed-154c-47c7-b16d-cbba5d8469eb
396f8e63-1950-4c36-9524-c1dec8728ffd
62cba3bd-a855-4141-8460-7ff838ecea62
b7f4f753-b479-413a-abcd-34d08436eb85
c0fd6e61-edb1-4dce-94ac-7d0529860e1f
c42f8c98-c285-4552-af9f-2f4d8e89b9e8
8cb77021-eb4f-4cfa-a4a3-e649f6a53c03
cb7f4b8d-976a-4481-919e-c8ff7d384cc6
e15fd2bb-5409-4a8b-9fdc-bf1e5862db58
27b97893-aae7-4a9a-aae1-0fc21a099209
1abc2c2f-94f2-4546-b912-b85bc4ed0cb8
6bf264fb-1b82-48e3-966a-14e48a61a63e
9653faeb-7b3d-408e-93e3-bc729f259c75
a09f3eb6-0059-4a77-bf2f-4f7436508ba8
65e06948-2e6c-413f-a768-c3faf8108a6c
291ff491-4ff0-4fb2-b095-b3e66f2d7ca0
653535c7-0389-4077-8e72-3835fbd72d4d
61408fc8-4f45-48e0-b83a-40b6bfd76ad5
3ae8d547-bf4b-42ac-b083-a1662f1a5c82
4955c673-c5da-464c-8e14-a897df0774eb
a39bad90-5235-4679-945e-534bb47b8347
264a1f6e-adf4-45a7-b1b1-e6f3fc073447
a855025b-ee84-46d5-aedb-cbac9a5b1920
71b16a5b-3f6d-4d30-8a65-203959fe87a2
4f3f86f2-4e61-475a-bc1d-eb2112f23953
59da45de-c192-4885-8a55-9138ca49b33a
8f41df73-d9dc-4663-9f64-d090d7c5ca77
84f7103f-e9de-444f-b046-c02d75af0ed1
2738f733-7438-494c-9368-5fb700df93d1
777a3cd7-19ae-4181-b91d-9be8eaf30523
b6083731-a43e-4b5a-ac9a-94a3202103e7
f22873c1-6811-4025-8f0d-47d72d49e499
f262c369-f44a-4b90-8219-d29b33bc14e8
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
ea0d26f5-d8c4-4082-983a-8eeea29c6c54
```

as can be seen in the above there are a duplicate values in `UniversalIDS` column, also it is worth to mention that there are other columns in the data but cut out the problem causing column for simplicity.

so my question is how can I replace the duplicate values in `UniversalIDS` column with a new unique IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=["UniversalIDS"]), "UniversalIDS"] = uuid.uuid4()
```

is correct python but it sets one uuid for all duplicated elements, which means the elements wil still be duplicated after it's been executed.
You should create a Series with distinct uuids:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=["UniversalIDS"]), "UniversalIDS"] = pd.Series([uuid.uuid4() for _ in df.duplicated(subset=["UniversalIDS"])])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found basically the same as the previous answer when I reproduced your problem but came up with a slightly different solution so posting for reference:

```
for idx, _ in df[df.duplicated(subset=["UniversalIDS"])].iterrows():
    df.at[idx, 'UniversalIDS'] = uuid.uuid4()
```